# Where can I buy a Niagara USA Discovery Pass on the ground in Niagara?

Tags: niagara-falls

The [on-line pass](http://www.niagarausadiscoverypass.com/) has a service fee of $2. Also, due to travel uncertainties, I'm not sure exactly how long I'd get once I'm there at Niagara Falls. So, once I reach Niagara, where can I buy the Discovery Pass - is it available at the ticket counters for popular attractions such as Maid of the Mist, Cave of the Winds etc?

Comment: As far as I can tell, these passes are _only_ sold online. It's currently a holiday in the US so it's not really possible to inquire with a person right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Wikivoyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Niagara_Falls_%28New_York%29), you can buy the Discovery Pass at any of the attractions that it includes - ie Cave of the Winds, Maid of the Mist, the Gorge Discovery Center, Aquarium, Adventure Theatre, or Whirlpool Tours.

> You can combine all these attractions with a Niagara USA Discovery
>   pass for $35, which you can purchase at the attractions.